# ASP.NET - JavaScript onmouseout get original background

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, vb.net

I added this code into my gridview rowdataBound:

```
 e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#E2DED6';this.style.cursor='pointer'")
```

Now onmouseout I want the original background from the the CSS, I don't know much from JavaScript and jQuery so I would like to keep it to inline JavaScript if possible.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
 e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='default'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to keep it inline:

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=''")
```

That should remove the inline style, and default to the normal stylesheet.

You can also be more "sledge hammer", and remove the whole style attribute (this will remove all set inline styles though):

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.removeAttribute('style')")
```

This assumes that you have a css/class set on the element to default to.

An easier way to maintain this would be to use css classes instead:

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.className='myHoverClass'")
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.className=''")
```

Define your class in a stylesheet (or in the page):

```
.myHoverClass {
    background-color: #E2DED6;
    cursor: pointer; 
}
```

Comment: i used the example with the stylesheet, the cursor changed but the background not, do you know why?

Comment: @user2653652 one reason could be that you have set the background color through inline style. This will override any class. To test it, you could do: `e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.className='myHoverClass'; this.removeAttribute('style');")` (that will also clear any existing inline styles)

Comment: Yea adding 'this.removeAttribute('style'); works, it is becouse i use a standard asp.net gridview template. i added to the css background-color: #E2DED6 !Important, to make it overwrite the existed inline style and now it works like i wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Something Like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var oldgridcolor;
    function SetMouseOver(element) {
        oldgridcolor = element.style.backgroundColor;
        element.style.backgroundColor = '#ffeb95';
        element.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        element.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
    }
    function SetMouseOut(element) {
        element.style.backgroundColor = oldgridcolor;
        element.style.textDecoration = 'none';

    }
</script>
```

C#

```
protected void gvrecords_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Row.RowType== DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "javascript:SetMouseOver(this)";
      e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "javascript:SetMouseOut(this)";
    }
}
```

OR You can add the old color here `oldgridcolor = "OldColor"` directly too